# VS 2017 Installation - System Footprint

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I use Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise (academic license) at the moment but I am really unsatisfied with the whole install / uninstall experience. Is the [Uninstaller Tool](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller) provided by MS really able to remove every trace of the VS installation? 
If so, is it a good idea to switch to VS 2017 afterwards? MS claims, it would have less influence on registry etc. In my opinion it's especially annoying that the VS 2015 installation adds so many entries into the Windows "Installed apps/programs" overview (can't say the exact title, not using English version). Has this been improved in VS 2017?

Comment: A development environment is significantly more complex than your standard application, and yes, MS's uninstaller does a pretty good job of cleaning up. I'm not sure there is anything that can be done to improve your satisfaction outside of a little attitude readjustment, to be blunt, or a complete wipe and OS-reinstall.

Comment: I don't think it's inappropriate to ask that a software installation doesn't mess up the system - and MS does work on [this issue](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/6669672-wouldn-t-it-be-nice-if-visual-studio-could-work-li). What are the cons of providing every necessary framework as integral part of VS instead of installing it seperately? If they did, the problem would be solved more or less, no matter how complex the software is. 
This thread should answer to what extent this problem has been improved in version 2017.